# unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, mysqlconnector

Помогите пожалуйста, я начинающий программист С#. Столкнулся со следующей ошибкой при подключении к БД:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Строка подключения:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(@"Database=formAppl; Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;");
```

Прочитав кучу статей по этой теме, менял последовательность свойств в строке подключения - не помогло.

Что не так в подключении? Если инфы не хватает, скажите что написать?

Comment: `SQLEXPRESS` - это Sql Server, СУБД от Microsoft.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, это я в курсе, почему к нему не подключается?

Comment: Потому что вы используете средство для подключения к MySql, а подключиться пытаетесь к MS SQL Server